# Sails.js blueprints

Tags: sails.js

I'm trying to build a very simple Rest API, I'd like to use sails (v0.11.0) blueprints.

Initially;

- I only want to use Http GET disable other methods
- Just return plain json, no views for *findOne*, *findAll*.
- Use a prefix like '/api/v1' but don't want to include all controllers, Example: Make controllerA url like '/api/v1/controllerA' but not '/api/v1/controllerB'

I have been playing with the blueprints but I couldn't be able to do all above. Sorry for too many questions all at once! but I really appreciate if somebody can help.

Thanks

Comment: This is all available in the sails documentation: http://sailsjs.org/#!/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I only want to use Http GET disable other methods

[You should override](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-docs/blob/master/reference/blueprint-api/blueprint-api.md#overriding-blueprints) built-in blueprints by creating files in your `/api/blueprints` folder with empty functions or throwing errors.

> Just return plain json, no views for findOne, findAll

I guess this is default behaviour of sails blueprints.

> Use a prefix like '/api/v1'

Sails [has blueprints configuration](http://sailsjs.org/#!/documentation/reference/sails.config/sails.config.blueprints.html) (in your /config folder). There you can set useful `prefix` and/or `restPrefix` options that are designed to do exactly what you want

> but don't want to include all controllers

You [should set _config object](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-docs/blob/master/reference/blueprint-api/blueprint-api.md#disabling-blueprints-on-a-per-controller-basis) in your controller to be:

```
_config: {
    actions: false,
    shortcuts: false,
    rest: false
}
```

Comment: Thanks, your answer was helpful.